# QT header included but does not find identifier for QSslError

Tags: qt, header, compiler-errors, 64-bit, identifier

I have downloaded QT 4.8.1 Source(everywhere-commercial-version). 
And compiled 64bit Version of QT with Visual Studio 2008 Pro under Windwos 7 64bit.

After that, i created a simple QT Application Project in vs2008.

but if i add the QSslError Class for test in my code like following.

```
#include <QSslError>
..

Qt64Test::Qt64Test(QWidget* parent, Qt::WFlags flags): QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QSslError a;
}
```

then i get C2065 error by compiling.

1>.\qt64test.cpp(10) : error C2065: 'QSslError': undifined identifier

But the header is included!

QTDIR is correctly set. And all QT include path settings are also correctly set.

i don't know why vs2008 compiler does not see this identifier.

the header file(qsslerror.h) look like this:

```
#ifndef QSSLERROR_H
#define QSSLERROR_H

#include <QtCore/qvariant.h>
#include <QtNetwork/qsslcertificate.h>

QT_BEGIN_HEADER

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

QT_MODULE(Network)

#ifndef QT_NO_OPENSSL

class QSslErrorPrivate;
class Q_NETWORK_EXPORT QSslError
{
public:
    enum SslError {
        NoError,
//..
```

(And QT_NO_OPENSSL is not defined in my code.)

Comment: Did you configure Qt for openssl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your Qt build was not configured with OpenSSL support.  The define will be in qconfig.h

Comment: openssl support is a defalut config. and this can not be the reason, because this error message comes at compile time, not at linking. So.. if header or class declaration is in sight, it should be compilable. The problem is, even if class declaration is visible by adding header, it will not compile.

Comment: The point is, QT_NO_OPENSSL is defined by Qt (in qconfig.h) if it was not configured with that support.  This will cause compilation (not linking) to fail in exactly the way you describe.

Comment: @DanMilburn what would be the proper procedure to counter this (considering a Qt that was simply installed from the pack found in Qt Project)? Just edit the `qconfig.h` or the Qt library will have to be recompiled?

Comment: @Momergil Qt must be recompiled.